# Using Kit Kat DatePicker in Lollipop Device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to show a `DatePickerDialog` in my apps. But I realized that the `DatePickerDialog` that show up depends on the phone OS. My question is how can I show `KitKat` style `DatePicker` in `Lollipop` OS? I know this is possible because some apps like Facebook is using it.

This is what I want

[image: DatePicker]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `android:calendarViewShown="false"` and `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` in the datepicker xml. I believe the former is for Kitkat and below, while `datePickerMode` applies to Lollipop.

Comment: Currently I'm using DatePickerDialog, is there a way to set the mode or I must create a custom dialog?

Comment: It works! I'm using DatePicker in custom Dialog. Thanks a lot

Comment: i am unable to find any method in datePickerDialog that sets the calendar view shown from the code

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

Comment: but this is deprecated with API 24

Comment: the answer is not working on my device, I want to show the datepicker as showen in kitkat in my lolipop device. I did mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false‌​); but unable to see any change the new calendar of lolipop is coming on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolve  that problem , 
you need to use theme with

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

with

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

then it shows kitkat version in lolipop phone 
if u need some some the 
mail me any time

@aakash4un2me@gmail.com